# How do I insert a second level column and value into a Pandas DataFrame, whilst keeping it in line with the first level column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

The below code creates the relevant Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

columns_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Apple','Apple','Banana'], ['Light_Green','Red','Yellow']])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=None,columns=columns_index,index=[1])
df.loc[:,('Apple','Light_Green')] = 10
df.loc[:,('Apple','Red')] = 0
df.loc[:,('Banana','Yellow')] = 5


    Apple           Banana
    Light Green Red Yellow
1   10          0   5
```

Then I run the following code to insert a new value (and a new first level column header into the DataFrame):

```
df.loc[:,('Apple','Dark_Green')] = 1
```

This, however, produces a DataFrame with the data ordered as follows:

```
    Apple           Banana  Apple
    Light_Green Red Yellow  Dark_Green
1   10          0   5       1.0
```

How do I insert this value (and new first level column header) into the DataFrame in the most Pythonic way and ensure that the Dark_Green header is within the Apple category, so that the DataFrame is as below:

```
    Apple                       Banana
    Light_Green Red Dark_Green  Yellow
1   10          0   1           5
```

Is there a different method to use to insert the data or is this method ok, with some kind of code deployed to re-sort the DataFrame after the best approach?

Note: I specifically need the DataFrame to be adjusted dynamically over and over again, so creating the DataFrame from the outset with the Dark_Green header is not a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Doing with `sort_index`

```
df=df.sort_index(level=0,axis=1)
       Apple                 Banana
  Dark_Green Light_Green Red Yellow
1        1.0          10   0      5
```